# Images in NSButton and NSImageView Blurred

Tags: objective-c, macos, image, cocoa, interface-builder

I am completely stumped here; I have a series of small images I'm tinkering with and making into buttons:

[image]

And as you can see they are all decently crisp and sharp, and retain this when I open the png files in Preview and what not.

However, when I use them in `NSButtons` and `NSImageViews` in Interface Builder, setting Scaling to None:

[image]

The images become horribly blurred. What am I doing wrong? I don't know where to start and what to try; should I go back to the icons and try to make them pixel perfect? Does it have to do with anti-aliasing or something along those lines?

---

**EDIT:**
For some reason, it seems as if the NSButtons and NSImageViews are loading the high resolution versions of the images, even though I'm on a normal display, which can be identified by a slight light blue stroke I added to them. For some reason, Quartz Debug does not identify these as high resolution images and there's no red tint. Removing references to the @2x images does fix the problem... but...

Comment: Are you viewing the images on a Retina display? If so, are they appropriately sized and named (@2x)?

Comment: This is not a Retina display, though I do have @2x-named images accompanying the 100% sized ones!

Comment: Try setting your view mode as aspect fit

Comment: @alpz I forgot to specify that this was OS X. Thanks for reminding me! (I don't think there's an "aspect fit" option on Mac)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check out session 245 in the `WWDC 2012` videos `Advanced Tips and Tricks for High Resolution on OS X` in the first section on `NSImage` you'll find out why.

`NSImage` doesn't have any concept of high resolution - it just uses the smallest image that has more pixels than the space it has to fill - so if your `NSImageView` is bigger in dimension than your 1x image it will use the 2x image as it has more pixels.

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem before. It seems that if your image's DPI isn't 72, the image size will be wrong. You can get the real size use the code below.

```
NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"image"];
NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[image TIFFRepresentation]];
NSSize size = NSMakeSize([rep pixelsWide], [rep pixelsHigh]);
[image setSize: size];
```

Comment: Well, the images were at 72 dpi, and the code yields the right size.

Answer (score 1):

When specifying image names in Interface Builder and `[NSImage imageNamed:]`, make sure to use `foo` instead of `foo.png`. While iOS is smart enough to add the `@2x` in the later case, Mac OS X is not. It will load the non-retina image in the later case, but will add the `@2x` in the first case (if such an image is present).

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigning the images to your `Buttons` in IB or in Code?

If you are doing it in code, maybe creating a copy of the image (e.g. `[myImage copy]`), and assigning that copy to your button may solve this.

Comment: I'm using IB since it's less of a hassle in some ways.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (drawing icons in custom NSOutlineView), I had to make sure that the x,y origin of the drawRect is rounded to int values:

```
NSMakeRect( round(NSMinX(cellFrame)-iconSize.width), 
round(NSMidY(cellFrame)-(iconSize.height/2.0f)), …);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a response to the earlier post about DPI, but I was unable to reply directly to it. The code in that post gave the true pixel dimensions for me (that is, it did not indicate any trouble). However, image DPI was definitely the culprit in my case. The symptoms I was seeing were:

- With my NSImageViews set to No Scaling, the images would appear squashed.
- With my NSImageViews set to Axes Independently, most images would appear correctly if the dimensions of the NSImageViews were set to exactly match the dimensions of the image.
- However, even in this case, some images had strange artifacts in them that were not there when viewing the same image via Preview or elsewhere (or even via Interface Builder, for that matter -- they only appeared at runtime).

The images that had trouble were at a DPI other than 72. When I re-created the images at 72 DPI, all of the above behavior disappeared.

This was a pretty confounding issue -- I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just needed to set image scaling to none:

In Interface Builder

[image]

In code

```
NSImageCell *image;
[image setImageScaling:NSImageScaleNone];

NSButtonCell *button;
[button setImageScaling:NSImageScaleNone];
```